# Identifying UUID

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I am building a application where i will scan for all bluetooth devices and connect to the interested bluetooth device.
I read that I need the UUID of the device so that i can connect to it.

I am using the following code to get the UUIDS

```
Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
Class[] par = {};
Method method = cl.getMethod("getUuids", par);
Object[] args = {};
ParcelUuid[] retval = (ParcelUuid[]) method.invoke(device, args);
return retval;
```

Now this is returning an array of UUID's. Now how do i identify which UUID i must use to connect?

Comment: Please don't use tags in the question's title. The tags at the bottom are more than enough for users to see what is the problem about.

Comment: Luksprog : I just tought that it would be easier to read and the visibility will be more !

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that any Bluetooth device might provide multiple services. Each service will have its own UUID. You might identify the UUID you need to use by inspecting its Protocol Identifier (the first two bytes). There's a list [here](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers-overview/service-discovery).